# Formatting removed for google docs embed in gmail via app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I have a scenario where I need to schedule an email at particular time every-day but the content of an email is present in some google doc and update on timely bases. So currently I am manually sending email and paste those content into my email but I want to automate the same.

So by doing search I found, it can be possible via google apps-script and I have written some script as below :

```
  var id = '<my_Id>';
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id="+id+"&exportFormat=html";
  var param = {
    method      : "get",
    headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    contentType: "text/html",
    muteHttpExceptions:true,
  };
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText();
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, 'DSR', 'html only', {htmlBody:html});
```

Script is working fine and I can see the contents into email but the google doc has some formatting like back-ground, foreground color, table but in email it is shows as only plain text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

https://gist.github.com/erickoledadevrel/11143648

the problem is html has to be inline

Thanks.